# Neo4j unique IDs by tree with root node counter?

Tags: neo4j, uniqueidentifier

Is using a tree with a counter on the root node, to be referenced and incremented when creating new nodes, a viable way of managing unique IDs in Neo4j? In a previous question on performance on this forum ([Neo4j merge performance VS create/set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403504/neo4j-merge-performance-vs-create-set#)), the approach was described, and it occurred to me it may suggest a methodology for unique ID management without having to extend the Neo4j database (and support that extension). However, I noticed this approach has not been mentioned in other discussions on best practice for unique ID management ([Best practice for unique IDs in Neo4J and other databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870292/best-practice-for-unique-ids-in-neo4j-and-other-databases)).

Can anyone help validate or reject this approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a singleton node (I'll give it the label `IdCounter` in my example) to hold the "next-valid ID counter" value. There is no need for it be part of any "tree" or for it to have any relationships at all.

When you create the singleton, initialize it with the first id value that you want to use. For example:

```
CREATE (:IdCounter {nextId: 1});
```

Here is a simple example of how to use it when creating a new node.

```
MATCH (c:IdCounter)
CREATE (x {id: c.nextId})
SET c.nextId = c.nextId + 1
RETURN x;
```

Since all Cypher queries are transactional, if the node creation did not happen for any reason, then the `nextId` increment would also not be done, so you should never end up with any gaps in assigned id numbers.

However, to avoid re-using the same id number, you would have to write your queries carefully to ensure that the increment always happens whenever you create a new node (using `CREATE`, `CREATE UNIQUE`, or `MERGE`).

Comment: Ahh yes, that's even simpler - thank you very much. But are there any gotchas to this? A singleton counter node solution is not mentioned in the best practice discussion I referenced above, which makes me wonder. What about scalability/high availability? Would you expect any issues using this solution in a Neo4j cluster architecture?

Comment: I have a script of a few hundred `MERGE` statements to initially load up some data to my database, which has been working fine. When I added the `MATCH...SET` clauses, however, the script fails in the browser with the message "Expected exactly one statement per query but got: 267". I guess that's because I need to run 267 transactions instead of 1 transaction with 267 `MERGE`s.

Comment: You need to make sure that you do not put any semicolons in the middle of a query, as a semicolon indicates the end of a statement. Also, you only need to do a `MATCH (c:IdCounter)` once per statement. Finally, you have to be very careful with your `MERGE` statements, to make sure they work as expected.

Comment: In addition, I do not expect this to be a very scalable solution. I may add more information later.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Without the semicolons it is seen as one statement but an invalid one. As you suggested, I created the counter node first:

Comment: `CREATE (:IdCounter {nextid:1})`

then created two nodes (using `CREATE` instead of `MERGE` this time), incrementing the counter with each create:

`MATCH (id:IdCounter) CREATE (a:Person {Name:"Ringo"}) SET id.nextid = id.nextid + 1
MATCH (id:IdCounter) CREATE (a:Person {Name:"George"}) SET id.nextid = id.nextid + 1`

and I get this error message:

`WITH is required between SET and MATCH (line 2, column 1 (offset: 84))`

These work individually, but I want to script them. Thank you for considering.

Comment: As the error states, you need to insert `WITH id` between `SET` and `MATCH` clauses.

Comment: Yep, that worked. I missed the `id` after the WITH previously. Also, in my example in the previous comment I didn't set an id on each node (the whole point)... but that all works now. Scalability is still a concern, but hopefully this gets me a starter unique identifier, and with no database extension required. Thanks.